# Java Database adding to row I deleted?

Tags: java, mysql, database

Ok So I have a program where I add new Players to a database, and where I load them users into a list. The problem is when I delete a user, then go to add a new user the new player gets added in to where the old user was. Basically because that spot is free now and I use:

```
rs.moveToInsertRow();
```

is there a way that when adding a new player it 'Always' adds to the end of the the database. Like when you delete a row from table to make the database compress so it has no gaps?

here is the code:

```
public static void Save() { try {

String Name = "#####";
 String Pass= "#####";
String Host = "######";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format(
"jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", Host, "####", "####"),
Name, Pass);
  Statement stmt = con.createStatement (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);



String sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


 rs.moveToInsertRow( );

    String userName= TestForm.UsernameTextField.getText(); //make this equal to whats in textfield
    String password= TestForm.PasswordTextField.getText(); //make this equal to whats in textfield

    String insertQuery="insert into Accounts (`Username`,`Password`) values ('"+userName+"','"+password+"');";
    stmt.executeUpdate(insertQuery);

 stmt.close();
 rs.close();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("ERROR");
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I didn't knew tables could have gaps... Maybe you mean you have gaps in your PK sequence?

Comment: Just a side note you should use [Prepared Statements](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) to insert data..

Comment: I would recommend using an auto_increment integer primary key. auto_increment does not repeat entries, even if entries are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

What's your table create statement? `SHOW CREATE TABLE Accounts ;`

Seems like an [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) integer primary key in the table would help your issue.

Comment: I use godaddys mysql, where it has a gui to create a table and coloumns etc. How would I go about this? Like increment when I add and decrement when I delete then add new row to total++ ? What is the sql command to add to a certain row? also if the table has 5 rows could you add to row 6? thanks!

Comment: @Peter i posted SQL to show table structure: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Accounts` or `DESCRIBE Accounts`